# Finding Button within Button Group Class Using Selenium Webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My end goal is to be able to click Yes or No on a webpage.

Using fire bug I can see the Yes and No buttons reside in a class called "btn-group"

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-default answer-toggle" aria-label="..." role="group">
     <button class="btn ng-pristine ng-valid active btn-secondary ng-touched" btn-radio="true" ng-model="consultation.previousSoundVoid" ng-class="{'btn-secondary': consultation.previousSoundVoid}" type="button">
          Yes
     </button>
     <button class="btn ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" btn-radio="false" ng-model="consultation.previousSoundVoid" ng-class="{'btn-secondary': consultation.previousSoundVoid == false}" type="button">
          No
     </button>
</div>
```

I think I could find Element by XPath but I am trying to improve my Selenium skill.

I am hoping there is a way to first find the "btn-group" class then somehow choose Yes or No within that.

Or be able to create variables for both the Yes and No options.  If I do:

```
var button = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.ClassName("btn"));
```

It returns 21 options.  I found that:

```
button[15].Text     returns "Yes"
button[16].Text     returns "No"
```

Instead of having to look through all 21 results and worrying about if the index changes, can I search the results by text somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to identify those element using `text` and `xpath` since they do not have any unique id

```
//button[.='Yes']
```

Desperate to use `cssSelector`?

```
.btn.ng-pristine.ng-valid.active.btn-secondary.ng-touched
```

since it is a compound class

You can also go for `nth-child()` with css

```
[role='group']>button:nth-child(1)
```

whereas `2` will let you select the button with text `No`

Answer (score 3):

Case 1: **When** *answer-toggle* **is unique in the HTML page**

```
Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'answer-toggle')]//button[contains(text(),'Yes')]")).Click();
```

This will first locate a div that has *answer-toggle* in its class name and the find a **button** that has text **Yes**

Case 2: *answer-toggle* **is not unique in your HTML page the you can use the complete class name as follows**

```
Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='btn-group btn-group-default answer-toggle']//button[contains(text(),'Yes')]")).Click();
```

or

```
Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class,'btn-group btn-group-default answer-toggle']//button[contains(text(),'Yes')]")).Click();
```

Case 3: **If there is only one button in your HTML page that has text "Yes"**

```
Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Yes')]")).Click();
```

Same thing applies for **No** button. You just have to replace **Yes** with **No**.

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely multiple options to locate the buttons, but I think that `answer-toggle` class sounds a good thing to rely on:

```
var buttons = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.answer-toggle button.btn"));
```